# Print output into a text file in linux

Tags: linux, file, diff

Hello I am trying to get the difference between to text files. There are a lot of differences and viewing them in terminal is making it volatile since I cannot save them. I want to view and save the diff. How would I catch the output and print it to a text file??

Code I am using for getting the diff is `diff -i -w -B file1.txt file2.txt`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save to text file:

```
diff -i -w -B file1.txt file2.txt > diff.txt
```

Write directly to printer:

```
diff -i -w -B file1.txt file2.txt | lpr
```

Write saved text file to printer

```
lpr diff.txt
```

'Hope that helps .. PSM

PS:
Here's a link on Linux command-line printing:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-Usage-HOWTO-2.html

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking,
`command > output.txt`
and in your case 
`diff -i -w -B file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt`

and if you want to append the result
`command >> output.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Just redirect it to a file:

```
 diff -i -w -B file1.txt file2.txt > output.diff
```

If you'd like to know more about redirecting output, the advanced details vary shell-to-shell, but here's a [reference for bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) and a [cheat-sheet](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) for the common stdout/stderr redirects.